# Creat individual .php?id= links for each of the products in products.php file

Tags: php, mysql, e-commerce

On my products page, there are several different product grids(created with bootstrap) in which, all of my products are displayed. What I am trying to do is to create detailed pages for each of the products the page has.
**products.php:**

```
<?php
session_start();
include('inc/config.php');
?>
<html>
<body>
some content
<div class="row">
        <?php
                            $query=mysql_query("select*from cars");
                            while($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

                            ?>
        <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="text-center">
                                <?php echo "<h2>".$data['make']." ".$data['model']." </h2>"; ?></h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body text-center">
                            <p class="lead">
                                <?php echo '<img src="cartest/'.$data['image'].'" class="img-responsive" />'; ?></p>
                        </div>
                        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush text-center">
                            <li class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-ok text-danger"></i><?php echo "<h4>".$data['price']." </h4>"; ?></li>
                            <li class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-ok text-danger"></i>Unlimited projects</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-ok text-danger"></i>27/7 support</li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="panel-footer">
                            <?php echo '<a class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-default" a href="product-details.php?id='.$data['carId'].'">Details</a>';?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <? } ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**product-details.php:**

```
<?php
session_start();
include('inc/config.php');
?>
<html>
    <body>
    some content
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <?php
      $id = $_GET['carId'];
      $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cars WHERE carId='$id'") or die(mysql_error());
      $data = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    ?>
    <div>
        <?php echo '<img alt="" src="cartest/'.$data['image'].'"></a>'; ?>                                              
    </div>
```

As you can see, I managed to create individual links for each of the products but is there a way of displaying the individual pages using something like a main template which its gonna change the content section according to the product that has been clicked? or do i have to create countless pages for each of the products?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Never use variables directly in your queries without filtering and escaping their content! Your site will be vulnerable to SQL injections attacks. Take a look at the `filter_input` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change something in template, you need to prefer it.
for.eg. for unique background you can use something like this:

```
<div id="product" style="background: url($mybgurl)"></div>
```

In this case `$mybgurl` it's url for this product's image, fetched from db.

P.S: Google for MVC or template engine.